# How to animate div using jQuery to the height of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a div called `.A` coded as `height:auto` that has a height rendered based on the text contained within. I have another div on the page called `.B` that I need to animate down using jQuery based on the height of the first div, `.A`.

I have attempted using the following jQuery function, without much luck. The idea was to have jQuery ascertain the height of `.B` then apply a padding to `.B`, however it is not grabbing the correct height. I have also tried using `'marginTop'`

```
jQuery('div.A').animate({'paddingTop': jQuery('div.B').height()},500);
```

Desparate for help! Will pay with up-votes and generous compliments.

Comment: please post your code i.e. div A and B

Comment: Your code seems to work just as it is: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/AyxJP/1 ( Note that I did change padding into margin so that it's more apparent that the animated distance is correct. ) You can also try checking what the value is.. http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/AyxJP/3/ -- By the way: Getting dimensions of hidden elements can be tricky in some browsers.

Comment: @Joonas SPOT ON. The depth of knowledge of SO users always astounds me. This issue was caused because div.A was set to display:none;, by changing this to use visibility, jQuery was able to capture the correct height. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `.outerHeight(true)`:

```
jQuery('div.A').animate({ paddingTop : jQuery('div.B').outerHeight(true)},500);
```

#### Description for [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) from docs

Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding, border, and optionally margin. Returns an integer (without "px") representation of the value or null if called on an empty set of elements.

**Note:**

> The top and bottom padding and border are always included in the .outerHeight() calculation; if the includeMargin argument is set to true, the margin (top and bottom) is also included.

Comment: Was actually an issue with jQuery being unable to capture the height of div.A, which was set to display:none;. I fixed by changing the div styling to visibility:hidden; and adjusting visibility with jQuery in the function. The height renders correctly now for paddingTop. Sorry for lack of information in the original post, but thanks for the help!